# Spark Datasets and variance

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

**Context**

I have created a function that takes a `Dataset[MyCaseClass]` and returns an array of the elements of one of its columns

```
 def columnToArray(ds: Dataset[MyCaseClass], columnName: String): Array[String] = {
   ds
     .select(columnName)
     .rdd
     .map(row => row(0).toString)
     .collect
 }
```

It works fine with case class

```
case class MyCaseClass(
  fieldA: String,
  fieldB: String,
  fieldC: String
)
```

**Problem**

I need to reuse the functionality with a `Dataset` of some other type. In an attempt to generalize, I declared the `Dataset`'s type as `AnyRef` but when I use it with the aforementioned case class I get the following error

> type mismatch;  found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[com.my.package.MyCaseClass]  required: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[AnyRef] Note: com.my.package.MyCaseClass <: AnyRef, but class Dataset is invariant in type T. You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)

I suppose that type `T` mentioned in the error is the type of `Dataset` so I cannot change its variance. Is there some other way I can generalize this function somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this particular function exact type of the `Dataset` doesn't matter, so I'd simply:

```
def columnToArray(ds: Dataset[_], columnName: String): Array[String] = {
 ds
   .select(columnName)
   .rdd
   .map(row => row(0).toString)
   .collect
}
```